# Why am I getting an incompatible pointer types error?

Tags: c

I have studied C pointers, and am wondering why the compiler is issuing an incompatible pointer types error in the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


const char *months(int n);
int main() {
    char **p = months(2);

    printf("%s", **p);
}

const char *months(int n) {
  const char *m[] = {
        "Invalid month",
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "Aprli"
    };
    return (n == 0 || n > 12) ? m[0] : m[n];
}
```

I expect printf to display "February" as month, but I get that error 
"Incompatible pointer types initializing 'char **' with an expression of type 'const char *'"
during compile process .

If not wrong months function return pointer to "n" month. Next I create a pointer p to point the result of months function.

What is wrong here ?

Comment: Declare, and use, `p` as pointer to char rather than pointer to pointer to char.

Comment: You may want to also check for negative `n` in the `months()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` needs to match the return type of `months`, which is `const char *`. This should work:

```
const char *p = months(2);
printf("%s", p);  // no need to dereference to *p here
```

Comment: Well. Why then printf("%s", p) works ? I thought that p shows memory address rather than the value

Comment: Yes, and `printf()` wants to know, at which memory address it's supposed to "start printing". `*p` would pass the first `char`'s value, which isn't what you want, right?

Answer (score 5):

You can't have a "pointer to point at the result" without storing the result somewhere, you're trying to store the result (which is `char *`) in a variable of type `char * *` and that doesn't work.

You need:

```
char *result = (char *) month();
char **p = &result;
```

Also, you should make the `m` vector `static`, since it's a bit gross to return a pointer to a local variable of a function.

I added the cast since you're dropping the `const`ness, which is also a bit ugly but I didn't want to change it around too much.

Comment: You added the cast because otherwise your code would be not valid. There is no implicit conversion from `const char *` to `char *`.

Comment: Returning a pointer to a local variable isn't just "gross", it doesn't work. Its memory may be overwritten at any moment.

Comment: @ugoren: In general yes, but I'm pretty sure this would work in "most" cases, since the data is just a static string anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
char **p = months(2);
```

should be

```
const char *p = month(2);
```

because your `month` function returns a `const char *` and not a `char **`.

and

```
printf("%s", **p);
```

should be

```
printf("%s", p);
```

because `p` is the pointer to your string.

Answer (score 0):

```
const char *months
```

this returns a `const char*`

```
char **p = months(2);
```

this tries to convert a `const char*` to a `char**`.

What's wrong is the conversion.

The correct way would be

```
const char *p = months(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
#include <stdio.h>

const char *months(int n); 

int main(void) 
{
    const char *p = months(2);
    printf("%s \n", p); 
    return 0;
}

const char *months(int n)  
{
    const char *m[] = { 
        "Invalid month",
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "Aprli"
    };  
    return (n == 0 || n > 12) ? m[0] : m[n];
}
```